# Sublime Regex Search and Replace

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext3

Trying to use Sublime to update the urls of only some lines in a sql table dump.

in this case the line that I need to single out has the string 'themo_showcase_\d_image' which is easy to match. In the same string what I actually need to replace is the url column so that it reads 'https://www.example.com/' to 'http://www.example.com'

Anyone able to help shed some light on this? I've got thousands of these insert records that I need to modify.

ex:

original string:

('8630', '1328', 'themo_showcase_1_image', 'https://www.example.com/'),

to:

('8630', '1328', 'themo_showcase_1_image', 'http://www.example.com/'),

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Can you provide sample inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: if the string you want to match is always in the tail part of the same URL, something like `(http)(://[^<>"']+/themo_showcase_\d_image)` could be replaced with `$1s$2` (not sure what precise syntax Sublime uses).

Comment: just updated the question with the original string and expected output after this operation has been correctly. The idea is use the regex to filter out the strings that I don't want to modify, and then replace the protocol of the url of what's left.

Answer (score 0):

- Find: `'themo_showcase_\d_image', 'http\Ks` you could use `\d+` if there are more than 1 digit
- Replace: `LEAVE EMPTY`